# pandas column values to row values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a dataset (171 columns) and when I take it into my dataframe, it looks like this way-

```
ANO MNO UJ2010  DJ2010   UF2010 DF2010   UM2010 DM2010    UA2010    DA2010 ...
1   A   113   06/01/2010    129 06/02/2010  143 06/03/2010  209 05/04/2010 ...
2   B   218   06/01/2010    211 06/02/2010  244 06/03/2010  348 05/04/2010 ...
3   C   22    06/01/2010    114 06/02/2010  100 06/03/2010  151 05/04/2010 ...
```

Now I want to change my dataframe like this way -

```
    ANO MNO Time        Unit
    1   A   06/01/2010  113
    1   A   06/02/2010  129
    1   A   06/03/2010  143
    2   B   06/01/2010  218
    2   B   06/02/2010  211
    2   B   06/03/2010  244
    3   C   06/01/2010  22
    3   C   06/02/2010  114
    3   C   06/03/2010  100
....
.....
```

I tried to use `pd.melt`, but I think it does not fullfil my purpose. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`pd.lreshape`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/reshape.py#L820) as a close alternative to [`pd.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) after filtering the columns to be grouped under the distinct headers.

Through the use of  `pd.lreshape`, when you inject a dictionary object as it's `groups` parameter, the keys would take on the new header name and  all the list of column names fed as values to this `dict` would be cast under that single header. Thus, it produces a long formatted `DF` after the transformation.

Finally sort the `DF` w.r.t the unused columns to align these accordingly.

Then, a `reset_index(drop=True)` at the end to relabel the index axis to the default integer values by dropping off the intermediate index.

```
d = pd.lreshape(df, {"Time": df.filter(regex=r'^D').columns, 
                     "Unit": df.filter(regex=r'^U').columns})

d.sort_values(['ANO', 'MNO']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

[image]

---

If there's a mismatch in the length of the grouping columns, then:

```
from itertools import groupby, chain

unused_cols = ['ANO', 'MNO']
cols = df.columns.difference(unused_cols)

# filter based on the common strings starting from the first slice upto end.
fnc = lambda x: x[1:] 
pref1, pref2 = "D", "U"

# Obtain groups based on a common interval of slices.
groups = [list(g) for n, g in groupby(sorted(cols, key=fnc), key=fnc)]

# Fill single length list with it's other char counterpart.
fill_missing = [i if len(i)==2 else i + 
                [pref1 + i[0][1:] if i[0][0] == pref2 else pref2 + i[0][1:]]
                for i in groups]

# Reindex based on newly obtained column names.
df = df.reindex(columns=unused_cols + list(chain(*fill_missing)))
```

Continue the same steps with `pd.lreshape` as mentioned above but this time with `dropna=False` parameter included.

Comment: pd.lreshape is great +1 :-)

Comment: I might be wrong but couldnot find any documentation on `pd.lreshape`, Can you please explaing the code a bit more ? And can you please give me the documentation reference ?

Comment: *I've updated my post.* If you are on Jupyter, `pd.lreshape??` should show you the underlying code in a pop-up window. AFAIK, this is still in it's experimental stages currently and hence it's absence from the documentation pages.

Comment: Do they all start with the same `U` and `D` prefixes? If not, how are you planning on grouping them?

Comment: When I try to run your snippet in my dataset, it shows `ValueError: All column lists must be same length`. Do I need to fill all the `Nan`. Because there are some columns where there is no value at all for an` account`

Comment: Maybe try with keeping the missing values instead. Just add `dropna=False` inside the function call to `pd.lreshape` to match the length of both the lists passed.

Comment: `dropna = False` doesnot work it shows the same error

Comment: Alright, I've made an edit which hopefully solves that problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) but first create `MultiIndex` in columns with `%` and `//`.

`MultiIndex` values map pairs `Time` and `Unit` to second level of `MultiIndex` by floor division (`//`) by `2`, differences of each pairs are created by modulo division (`%`).

Then `stack` use last level created by `//` and create new level of MultiIndex in `index`, which is not necessary, so is removed by `reset_index(level=2, drop=True)`.

Last reset_index for convert first and second level to `columns`.

`[[1,0]]` is for swap columns for change ordering.

```
df = df.set_index(['ANO','MNO'])
cols = np.arange(len(df.columns))
df.columns = [cols % 2, cols // 2]

print (df)
           0           1    0           1    0           1    0           1
           0           0    1           1    2           2    3           3
ANO MNO                                                                    
1   A    113  06/01/2010  129  06/02/2010  143  06/03/2010  209  05/04/2010
2   B    218  06/01/2010  211  06/02/2010  244  06/03/2010  348  05/04/2010
3   C     22  06/01/2010  114  06/02/2010  100  06/03/2010  151  05/04/2010

df = df.stack()[[1,0]].reset_index(level=2, drop=True).reset_index()
df.columns = ['ANO','MNO','Time','Unit']
print (df)
    ANO MNO        Time  Unit
0     1   A  06/01/2010   113
1     1   A  06/02/2010   129
2     1   A  06/03/2010   143
3     1   A  05/04/2010   209
4     2   B  06/01/2010   218
5     2   B  06/02/2010   211
6     2   B  06/03/2010   244
7     2   B  05/04/2010   348
8     3   C  06/01/2010    22
9     3   C  06/02/2010   114
10    3   C  06/03/2010   100
11    3   C  05/04/2010   151
```

EDIT:

```
#last column is missing 
print (df)
   ANO MNO  UJ2010      DJ2010  UF2010      DF2010  UM2010      DM2010  UA2010
0    1   A     113  06/01/2010     129  06/02/2010     143  06/03/2010     209
1    2   B     218  06/01/2010     211  06/02/2010     244  06/03/2010     348
2    3   C      22  06/01/2010     114  06/02/2010     100  06/03/2010     151
```

```
df = df.set_index(['ANO','MNO'])
#MultiIndex is created by first character of column names with all another
df.columns = [df.columns.str[0], df.columns.str[1:]]
print (df)
            U           D     U           D     U           D     U
        J2010       J2010 F2010       F2010 M2010       M2010 A2010
ANO MNO                                                            
1   A     113  06/01/2010   129  06/02/2010   143  06/03/2010   209
2   B     218  06/01/2010   211  06/02/2010   244  06/03/2010   348
3   C      22  06/01/2010   114  06/02/2010   100  06/03/2010   151


#stack add missing values, replace them by NaN
df = df.stack().reset_index(level=2, drop=True).reset_index()
df.columns = ['ANO','MNO','Time','Unit']
print (df)
    ANO MNO        Time  Unit
0     1   A         NaN   209
1     1   A  06/02/2010   129
2     1   A  06/01/2010   113
3     1   A  06/03/2010   143
4     2   B         NaN   348
5     2   B  06/02/2010   211
6     2   B  06/01/2010   218
7     2   B  06/03/2010   244
8     3   C         NaN   151
9     3   C  06/02/2010   114
10    3   C  06/01/2010    22
11    3   C  06/03/2010   100
```

Comment: sure, give me a sec

Comment: as per column-row switch, your code works but the problem now is, I am missing values into a particular column. Actually its kind a doing left-shifting their values to other column. Am I able to make understand you the scenario ?

Comment: solution is easy - add parameter `dropna=False` - `df.stack(dropna=False)`

Comment: or problem is some all values in column is missing? eg. if your sample `UJ2010, DJ2010` then `DJ2010` is missing?

Comment: yeah, exactly that is the problem, there are some columns that is missing values. now what should I do ?

Comment: Nah same left column value shifting. It is not working for me

Comment: I think there has to be problem with column names, some dont align to pairs :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with [`pd.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) for this. The solution is simple - just stack all relevant columns (which are selected via iloc) vertically one after another and concatenate them:

```
def rename(sub_df):
    sub_df.columns = ["ANO", "MNO", "Time", "Unit"]
    return sub_df

pd.concat([rename(df.iloc[:, [0, 1, x+1, x]])
           for x in range(2, df.shape[1], 2)])

    ANO     MNO     Time    Unit
0   1       A   06/01/2010  113
1   2       B   06/01/2010  218
2   3       C   06/01/2010  22
0   1       A   06/02/2010  129
1   2       B   06/02/2010  211
2   3       C   06/02/2010  114
0   1       A   06/03/2010  143
1   2       B   06/03/2010  244
2   3       C   06/03/2010  100
0   1       A   05/04/2010  209
1   2       B   05/04/2010  348
2   3       C   05/04/2010  151
```

Comment: As, I said I have 171 columns so, do I need to change the the parameter inside the `concat` method?

Comment: @pdfarhad No you don't, it is already inlcuded via `df.shape[1]`. The range automatically adjusts to your input data frame.